# xlsfonts not showing .ttf fonts

Tags: linux, fonts, x11, truetype

The X11 Core font system should support ttf (truetype) & otf (opentype) formats:
https://x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xorg-docs/fonts/fonts.html

I've DL a font f.ttf & placed it in /user/share/fonts/ttf
Then

```
cd /user/share/fonts/ttf
mkfontscale
mkfontdir
xset fp+ /user/share/fonts/tff
xset fp rehash
```

The font path is updated (/user/share/fonts/ttf has been added) but

```
xlsfonts
```

doesn't show the font.

**I'm familiar with fontconfig & the xft system**. I'm trying to enable "old" X11 apps also use the ttf font as the ttf format should be supported.

Thanks

Comment: Look at the fonts.dir file that mkfontdir created, does it contain anything interesting?

Answer (score -1):

The issue was solved by removing whitespaces from the font filename, e.g."a b.ttf" won't show up in xlsfonts.
Renaming the file to "a_b.ttf" followed by `mkfontscale && mkfontdir && xset fp rehash` solves the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).